Closing my hamburger menu removes the navbar's responsiveness
I'm currently making a hamburger menu and its working fine. The problem arises when I try and make my website responsive. If I shrink the page, the buttons disappear and the burger menu icon appears. If I then expand the page before opening the menu, the hamburger menu disappears and the button reappear. no problems yet. If I open the menu and then expand the page, the same thing happens. No problems yet.
If I open the menu, then close it and THEN expand the page, the buttons don't reappear, but the burgermenu does disappear. What am I doing wrong here?


function Burgermenu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
  if (x.style.display == "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }

}
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.mobile-container {
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #555;
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar a {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
}

.navbar a.icon {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar #myLinks {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .navbar #myLinks {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
<div class="mobile-container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Logo</a>
    <div id="myLinks">
      <a href="#stuff">Stuff</a>
      <a href="#stuff">Stuff</a>
      <a href="#stuff">Stuff</a>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="Burgermenu()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>




Inline styles take precedence over matching stylesheet ones.
When you close the menu, you're setting display: none on directly on the element here:
if (x.style.display == "block") {
  x.style.display = "none";
}

Which is maintained when you expand the view and overrides your CSS rule here:
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .navbar #myLinks {
    display: block;
  }
}

What you could do instead is toggle an open class on the #myLinks element:


function Burgermenu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
  x.classList.toggle('open');
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.mobile-container {
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #555;
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar a {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
}

.navbar a.icon {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar #myLinks {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar #myLinks.open {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .navbar #myLinks {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
<div class="mobile-container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Logo</a>
    <div id="myLinks">
      <a href="#stuff">Stuff</a>
      <a href="#stuff">Stuff</a>
      <a href="#stuff">Stuff</a>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="Burgermenu()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>



